# Lucene.Net Index all files in a folder

Tags: file, indexing, directory, lucene.net

Is there a way to index all files in a specific folder?
Refer to a folder, and somehow add all the documents in the folder to the index without having to loop through all the files in the folder. In DtSearch, there was a method to "IndexFilesInFolder(foldername)"

Comment: lucene is a low level API to index any source of data. you might be interested into Solr, also available from apache

Answer (score 1):

There's a [demo directory](https://github.com/apache/lucene.net/tree/trunk/src/demo) in the Lucene.Net source which includes examples how to index all files in a folder, and searches the index. It works for basic text documents, you'll need to handle other document types to extract their content.